# Vol surface from Bloomberg API

Tags: bloomberg

Can someone tell me if it's possible to retrieve vol surface for different underlyings through the Bloomberg Open API (or else) for free or almost ?

I precise that I have a BBG terminal so I have an access.

I asked pricings to BBG on vol surface daily snapshots and the price is sky rocketing. So just asking for an alternative solution.

Comment: I haven't seen anything more affordable. Sorry.

Comment: As far as I can remember in `R` (I don't currently have a Bloomberg terminal):

`install.packages('Rblpapi');`
`require(Rblpapi);`
`iVolSurface <- bds("SPX Index", "IVOL_SURFACE_STRIKE")`

Hint: [`reshape2`](https://seananderson.ca/2013/10/19/reshape/) package will be useful, enough said ;)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, 2 possibilities via Bloom terminal for free:

1. use the  function in the terminal, then click on Asset / Export to Excel. Then the terminal will offer you to export "skew data" for free. There you will have in Excel a few clean market vols for different strikes/maturities.
2. Directly in Excel, using =BCHAIN(...) formula: just ask Bloom help Desk for a template with that formula. In theory you can use this formula to filter the type of options you want (calls/puts, moneyness, min volume, etc.) but in practice their filters don't work really well, you will have to filter the retrieved options chain yourself